# Product collection by store in admin

Tags: admin, adminhtml, collection, products

I know about method

```
public function addStoreFilter($store = null)
{
        if ($store === null) {
            $store = $this->getStoreId();
        }
        $store = Mage::app()->getStore($store);

        if (!$store->isAdmin()) {
            $this->setStoreId($store);
            $this->_productLimitationFilters['store_id'] = $store->getId();
            $this->_applyProductLimitations();
        }

        return $this;
}
```

But as you can see it doesn't work for $store->isAdmin(). 
I'm always getting "admin store" data.

So my question is: how to get product collection for specific store by SKU list under "admin" store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `addStoreFilter` method in your admin code as long as you pass the id of your frontend store as a parameter.

As you can see from the method if the `$store` variable is set based on the parameter using `Mage::app()->getStore()` method so that code will retrieve the frontend store based on the id you've passed.

Then it checks if that store is an admin store, as you've passed a frontend store id that `!$store->isAdmin()` condition will be true so it will properly apply the products limitations to the store you've passed.